# flex and .net 2.0 web service, how to allow access from other domains?

Tags: .net, vb.net, apache-flex, service

I created a project in flex builder with application server type set to none.

When I debug, I can access the web service from my local machine thats on a site http://mysite.com/ws/ws.aspx?wsdl

When I upload the flex app to mysite.com/myapp.html it works great.

But, when I upload it to myapp.mysite.com/myapp.html it wont access the web service.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Thanks

P.S. The WS was created with VB.net, and when I create a flex project with application server type set to .net, it wont access the WS from my local machine

this is my crossdomain.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

**My guess is that it isn't a flex problem, but a .net security feature... wich I don't know how to configure.

.NET won't allow apps to use it outside of its own domain.**

Comment: What does "it won't access the web service" mean? What kind of error you're getting?

Comment: it means flex returns a falut event, like if the web service didn't exist, maybe de web service only allows applications on its own domain, I don't think its a flex problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Flex does not allow accessing web services on remote hosts. This is a security feature of Flex. Since your Flex app is deployed at `myapp.mysite.com` it's under different host than the service at `mysite.com`.

You can add a `crossdomain.xml` to the mysite.com which Flex will check to see if the service allows access from different domains. The `crossdomain.xml` file must be located in the web root of the domain (`mysite.com/crossdomain.xml`). I've used the following contents to allow debugging use. Note that it allows all use so if you want to restrict the use in production, you need to modify it later.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
    "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" />
   <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

More information in [Flex documentation](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Flex:Accessing_Data), especially the [knowledge base article](http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=tn_14213&sliceId=1).

Comment: I've got a crossdomain.xml, I just added this line taken from your code <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/> everything else is the same. still no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the requests being made with Tamper Data (extension to Firefox). Check so that the app finds the crossdomain.xml file. If the path is off, that's your problem.

Comment: So after the crossdomain is fetched, what type of error is reported when trying to access the WebService? Oh, and a comment on your last comment in the question: There is no standard setting in .Net preventing WebService access cross domains. This restriction is imposed by flash since it is running on the client. If it wasn't, Flash could be used to sniff data on internal LANs.